# Unresolved Reference: context inside RecyclerView adapter class Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

I am new in using classes in Kotlin. How would I be able to solve this Unresolved references: context? I tried the same code on my MainActivity.kt and it works. What am I doing wrong here?

```
class ListAdapter : RecyclerView.Adapter<ListAdapter.ViewHolder>() {
    private val file = File(context.filesDir,"internalstoragefilename")
    private val contents = file.readText()
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Context is not available in Adapter by default. If you truly need it in this place, you could pass it as a constructor's parameter. E.g.

```
class ListAdapter(private val context: Context) : RecyclerView.Adapter<ListAdapter.ViewHolder>() {
    private val file = File(context.filesDir,"internalstoragefilename")
    private val contents = file.readText()
}
```